# Why is Win32_PnPEntity "InstallDate" property always null?

Tags: winapi, wmi

I'm trying to write a script that needs to grab the InstallDate of devices as seen in device manager. Yet when I run...

```
Select * From Win32_PnPEntity Where DeviceID = '<deviceID>'
```

...I only receive NULL results for the InstallDate property. 
When I view the "Details" tab for the desired device in Device Manager the date appears normally.

Comment: That is entirely normal.  It might have worked 15 years ago.

Comment: So is there a modern way to figure out the install date of a device in device manager programatically? EDIT: I checked the WMI documentation (again) and this article is only from 2018..... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-pnpentity    Is there documentation that leads you to believe this functionality is deprecated? Do you know what I should be using instead?

Comment: I can reproduce this issue and report it internally.